# Subdomain redirected to main domain

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, subdomain

When creating my new vps server which contains apache, I added a domain and a sub domain
but i'm confusing with a problem that the sub domain redirect me to main domain i thinks the problem comes from .htaccess file :

- **www.example.com**
- **www.two.example.com**
- The first one is is located in    `/var/www/example.com/`  contains wordpress cms.
- The second one is is located in   `/var/www/two.example.com/` contain only index.html.

Of course i was added a new entry A in the Web Application Firewall

```
two.example.com A <ip_of_vps>

www.two.example.com A <ip_of_vps>
```

and both of site are enabled with a2ensite

```
$ ls -all /var/apache/sites-enabled
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Mar  5 22:41 example.com.conf -> ../sites-available/example.com.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   50 Mar 22 01:16 example.com-le-ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com-le-ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37 Apr 20 03:42 two.example.com.conf -> ../sites-available/two.example.com.conf
```

When i ping two.example.com is good

And the resultat of apachectl -S

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost 
default server example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com- le-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com-le-ssl.conf:2)  alias www.example.com

*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:2)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:2) alias www.example.com
         port 80 namevhost two.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/two.example.com.conf:1) alias www.two.example.com
```

The configuration of /etc/apache2/sites-available/

For www.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
     ServerAlias www.example.com
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
     RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

For www.two.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName two.example.com
        ServerAlias www.two.example.com
        ServerAdmin two.example@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/two.example.com/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SecRuleEngine On

</VirtualHost>
```

and the .htaccess of www.example.com (wordpress) :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Les directives (lignes) entre 'BEGIN WordPress' et 'END WordPress' sont
# généré dynamiquement, et ne doivent uniquement être modifiées via les filtres WordPress.
# Toute modification des directives entre ces marqueurs sera outrepassée.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^adm/?$ /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^adm/register/?$ /wp-login.php?action=register [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^adm/lostpassword/?$ /wp-login.php?action=lostpassword [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RedirectMatch 404 /\.git.*
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Did you also add `www.two.example.com A <ip_of_vps>`?

Comment: @nix Yes it's already done

Comment: You reference `www.two.example.com` initially, but then switch to `two.example.com`? Do both hostnames resolve correctly and exhibit the same behaviour? There's nothing in your `.htaccess` file that would trigger a redirect. Can you confirm that this is actually an external 3xx redirect and what status code you are seeing?

Comment: Which URL did you use for the test? If it's `https://www.two.example.com` (note: HTTPS), then it would be the wordpress despite the domain name, because you don't have a HTTPS virtual host for the subdomain.